# YouTube Android Player API - Modify jar source

Tags: java, android, jar, youtube, android-youtube-api

I'm building an app that is using the [Youtube Android API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to play videos inside app, but I get an error when I run my app on Android L because the need of an IntentService to be explicit. In fact the Youtube API is currently using an implicit IntentService in it's source code inside jar file.
I want to change this behaviour to make the app also works on L. Can you explain me how to modify a class inside the jar file? Or have you better suggestion to solve the problem (still targeting Android API21) ?

Answer (score 0):

The **only solution** for this known problem is to **target a lower API level (like API 19)** an wait for an updated version of the Youtube SDK (I suppose that it will be released soon).

Answer (score 0):

I Used [ClassModifier_lib](https://cooltrickshome.blogspot.com/2019/01/classmodifier-utility-to-easily-modify.html) to edit and modify a class.

First unzip the code, edit the class with `ClassModifier_lib`. this will create a `project`mapp inside it you will find `modifiedClass`. open the jar with winrar and replace the `modifiedClass` inside it.